CSS subgrid adds uneven space between element
I am using subgrid to create card with even spacing. For some reason card adds lot of space between elements and space is different in FF and Chrome. Below is the code based on this tutorial.


.wrapper{
  margin:0;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fit, minmax(350px, 1fr));
  gap:1rem;
  margin-top:0rem;
  max-height:400px;
}
.wrapper p h2 {  margin:0px;}
.wrapper img {
  max-width:100%;
  display:block;
}
.box{
   border:1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding:1rem;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-rows:subgrid;
  grid-row:span 3;
}
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/400?random=1" />
    <h2>This is Title One</h2>
    <p>This is the short description of the article which will be used for now</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/400?random=4" />
    <h2>This is Title One</h2>
    <p>This is the short description of the article which will be used for now This is the short description of the article which will be used for now</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/400?random=3" />
    <h2>This is Title One</h2>
    <p>This is the short description of the article which will be used for now</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/400?random=2" />
    <h2>This is Title One</h2>
    <p>This is the short description of the article which will be used for now</p>
  </div>
</div>




paragraphs have automatic padding or margin or both (i dont remember). try forcing the padding and margin to be 0 and see if that works

.wrapper p h2 matches nothing. I suspect you meant .wrapper :is(p, h2)

It is because of how you limit the image size. For some reason in Firefox the height of the track is calculated before the images are shrunk by max-width:100%. (Though I can't find the spec for which is the correct behavior.)
To deal with problems caused by replaced elements within a grid or flex container, using a <div> wrapper usually does the trick, which is the case here.


.wrapper {
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(350px, 1fr));
  gap: 1rem;
  margin-top: 0rem;
  max-height: 400px;
}

.wrapper p h2 {
  margin: 0px;
}

.box > div {
  max-width: 100%;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: subgrid;
  grid-row: span 3;
}
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <div>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/400?random=1" />
    </div>
    <h2>This is Title One</h2>
    <p>This is the short description of the article which will be used for now</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/400?random=4" />
    </div>
    <h2>This is Title One</h2>
    <p>This is the short description of the article which will be used for now This is the short description of the article which will be used for now</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/400?random=3" />
    </div>
    <h2>This is Title One</h2>
    <p>This is the short description of the article which will be used for now</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/400?random=2" />
    </div>
    <h2>This is Title One</h2>
    <p>This is the short description of the article which will be used for now</p>
  </div>
</div>




It looks like a fix however space after image in firefox is still there which is not an issue if it remain same across all browser for rest of the element space can be adjusted by reducing margin

Hi @Learning, those space are expected. As seen in https://i.sstatic.net/9nYHAHBK.png, the space below the image are combined by the 1rem grid gap you defined and h2's default margin-top. As mentioned in @Alochi's comment, you didn't remove p and h2's margin successfully. If you are talking about the horizontal gap between images, they are from the 1rem padding of the box. I'll suggest this is a good chance to learn using browser's developer tools (f12).

agree with you confusing part for me was that 1rem gap for image was not highlighted in developer tool as it does for margin & padding. so i was wondering while it doesnt show any pointer to margin or padding? I will mark you answer correct as it a fix around.

The gap or the layout of grid/flex will be highlighted only if you click on the little grid/subgrid/flex button beside the element in the html tree.

One possible reason for the uneven spacing could be due to the way you are using the grid-template-rows: subgrid; property in the .box class. The subgrid value is not fully supported by all browsers yet, which could lead to inconsistent behavior.
To achieve a consistent grid layout with even spacing between the cards, you can consider using a different approach without relying on subgrid.
Here's an alternative solution using a simpler grid setup:
.wrapper{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(350px, 1fr));
  gap: 1rem;
}

.box{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.wrapper img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.wrapper h2, .wrapper p {
  margin: 0;
}

With this updated CSS, you have removed the grid-template-rows: subgrid; property from the .box class and simplified the styling.
By using grid-template-columns and gap properties in the .wrapper class, you can achieve a consistent grid layout with even spacing between the cards.
Make sure to test this updated code in both Firefox and Chrome to ensure consistent spacing between the cards across different browsers.

This is incorrect because 1. Subgrid is fully supported by all major browsers.  2. Removing subgrid means losing the shared tracks in .box, so the subitems won't align with each other anymore if the image/h2/p have different height

I want to use this as it has support of all major browsers. however i am not sure about the spacing issue. i tested it in FF & chrome it should not behave the way it is..
